# Find $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} \frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

We have $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},\:f_n(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1}$ and we need to prove that is uniform convergence using formula:

> $\lim _{n\to \infty } \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f_n(x)-f(x)| =0$

---

First step I prove that the sequence $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$. After it: $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1}$ and $(\frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1})'=\frac{-x^2+n^2+1}{(x^2+n^2+1)^2}$ but I don't understand what will help us to find supremum, in this case.

I need some help to find $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} \frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1}$.

**P.S:** The author says that  $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} \frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1}$ is equal with $\frac1{2n}$, but I think he's wrong, I'm not sure.

Comment: "The author says that...": for the correct $\sup$ see my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track.

**For $x \in [0,1]$**, you have
$$
f'_n(x)=\frac{-x^2+n^2+1}{(x^2+n^2+1)^2}>0
$$ **then**
$$
\sup_{x\in[0,1]} \left(\frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1}\right)= \left.\left(\frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1}\right)\right|_{x=1}=\frac{1}{n^2+2} \to 0, \quad \text{as}\,\, n \to +\infty,
$$ and the convergence is **uniform on** $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to find the supremum.

Note that, since $0 \leq x \le1$ you and $x^2+n^2+1 \ge n^2+1$, you have
$$0 \le \frac{x}{x^2+n^2+1} \le \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$
Hence $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x)| \le \frac{1}{n^2+1} \to 0$ as $n \to + \infty$

Comment: +1. I'd like to remark that in the vast majority of cases, estimating the supremum is easier than actually identifying the supremum.

Comment: @Ian suppose we have $\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}$, how do you estimate the supremum without identify? with $x\in \left[1,2\right]$

Comment: @Lucas Long divide: $\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}=1-\frac{1}{x^n+1}$. Now you can either note that it is increasing or just bound the second term.

Answer (score 1):

$f_n(x)$ is a positive function over $(0,1)$ and by the AM-GM inequality

$$ f_n(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+(n^2+1)}=\frac{1}{x+\frac{n^2+1}{x}}\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^2+1}}\tag{1} $$
with equality attained in $x=\sqrt{n^2+1}$. It follows that $f_n$ is an increasing function over $[0,1]$ and its supremum is simply given by $f_n(1)=\frac{1}{n^2+2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only roots of the derivative are $\pm\sqrt{n^2+1} \notin [0,1]$, the supremum is attained at the boundary. The left endpoint yields $0$ and the right one gives $\frac1{n^2+2} \to 0$.

$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f_n(x)-f(x)| = \frac1{n^2+2}$$